# Our replica set ID did not match that of our request target, replSetId: 62b25bace8cf8ce971157db0, requestTarget: mongo0:27017

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, git-bash, mongod

Estoy intentando configuracion en 3 respaldos de image mongo en docker-compose pero falla
Tengo 3 respaldos de mongo mongo0, mongo1 y mongo2 e intento hacer una configuracion con config en rs.initiate(config) y me da

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Our replica set ID did not match that of our request target, replSetId: 62b25bace8cf8ce971157db0, requestTarget: mongo0:27017, r
equestTargetReplSetId: 62b0fa71ee099ab7ba686a31",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible"
}
```

Estoy aprendiendo mongo y quiero utilizar 3 imagenes de mongo con docker estoy siguiendo un tutorial pero no se a que se deba el error
etoy utilizando windows 10 Home y gitbash

Este es mi docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo0:
    hostname: mongo0
    container_name: mongo0
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    environment: 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    ports: 
       - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongo1: 
    hostname: mongo1 
    container_name: mongo1 
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    environment: 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root 
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    ports: 
    - 27018:27017 
    restart: always 
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongo2: 
    hostname: mongo2
    container_name: mongo2 
    image: mongo:4.4.6 
    environment: 
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root 
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456 
    ports: 
    - 27019:27017
    restart: always 
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongo-express: 
    container_name: mongo-client 
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 9090:8081 
    environment: 
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root 
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: 123456 
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: "mongo0,mongo1,mongo2"
```

cuando ejecuto

```
docker-compose up -d
```

funciona correctamente pero cuando me meto a un servicio

```
docker exec -it mongo0 mongo
```

hice un error anteriormente y ejecute rs.initiate(), sin pasar ninguna configuracion y ahora me aparece como

```
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

intento pasarle el sigueinte config

```
config = {
    "_id": "rs0", 
    "version": 1,
    "members":[{
        "_id": 0, 
        "host": "mongo0:27017"
    }, 
    {
        "_id": 1, 
        "host":"mongo1:27017"
    }, 
    {
        "_id":2, 
        "host": "mongo2:27017"
    }
]
}
```

y inicializar con

```
rs.initiate(config)
```

pero me aparece el siguiente error:

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Our replica set ID did not match that of our request target, replSetId: 62b25bace8cf8ce971157db0, requestTarget: mongo0:27017, r
equestTargetReplSetId: 62b0fa71ee099ab7ba686a31",
        "code" : 103,
        "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible"
}
>
```

Llevo 2 dias intentado solucionarlo y no he podidio estoy triste